# Enable CORS for Azure Storage via Client-side Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, azure-storage

I am working on a Javascript library to create entities in Azure Storage Table. Luckily, [Azure supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx). CORS is disabled by default. Using [Set Table Service Properties API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452240.aspx) it is possible enable it for specific domains and methods for a limited time.

Enabling CORS requires you to make a [non-simple request](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/): `PUT` request against `https://<account-name>.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties` with headers `Authorization`, `x-ms-date`, `x-ms-version`. When the library makes that HTTP request, browser sends a preflight request to the URL first. Preflight request always fails, because CORS is not enabled for that URL. The actual request fails, since preflight request is failed.

In that case, it seems not possible to enable CORS for Azure Storage services via client side javascript methods. Is that so? Is there anybody who worked on these APIs and managed to get it working?

**NOTE:** Having a proxy method is always an option (among others). We can create an API on the server side to enable CORS or even create entities without any client side execution (which doesn't require CORS at all). Client wouldn't need to make any cross domain request. However, I am not looking for that. I am more interested in solving the issue using client side capabilities only.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to enable CORS using JavaScript code considering setting CORS is a one time operation and can be done outside of your application? I'm curious to know.

Comment: Enabling CORS doesn't have to be one time operation. If you want to dynamically update CORS rules with some expiration time for security reasons, you need to enable multiple times.

Comment: I believe you're confusing SAS with CORS. CORS rule don't have any expiry time whereas SAS do.